# Allowed memory size exhausted

Tags: fatal-error

I need you help here.
After updating to WordPress 4.4 locally all was fine ... but after updating on my server I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 41943040 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8193 bytes) in /home/proondernemer/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4461
```

Anyone know how to fix this error?

I tryed to add this code to wp-config:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
```

And I tried to add this code to my htaccess file:

```
php_value memory_limit 64M
```

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Ow and this is the URL: http://www.pro-ondernemer.nl/wp-admin/

Comment: Do you have direct access to the server?

Answer (score 1):

This is a memory issue and can be handled from the **wp-config.php** file if the server allows.

From what I see you have tried

`define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');`

which takes care of the front end, but if you still have memory issue in the admin end, then try

`define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M' );`

> Please note, this has to be put before wp-settings.php inclusion.

For a more detailed information check the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP) here.

Answer (score 0):

This error arise just because of memory issue, try to increase the memory

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');
```

hope it will work fine